# How to make a prediction in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have this code below.
How can I make a prediction of the stock return whether the price goes up or down, or to predict the stock price itself?

```
df = pd.read_csv('....csv')

input_data = df[['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']].values
targets = df['Return'].values


T = 10
D = input_data.shape[1]
N = len(input_data) - T # (e.g. if T=10 and you have 11 data points then you'd only have one sample)

Ntrain = len(input_data) * 2 // 3
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(input_data[:Ntrain + T - 1])
input_data = scaler.transform(input_data)

X_train = np.zeros((Ntrain, T, D))
Y_train = np.zeros(Ntrain)

for t in range(Ntrain):
  X_train[t, :, :] = input_data[t:t+T]
  Y_train[t] = (targets[t+T] > 0)

X_test = np.zeros((N - Ntrain, T, D))
Y_test = np.zeros(N - Ntrain)

for u in range(N - Ntrain):
  t = u + Ntrain
  X_test[u, :, :] = input_data[t:t+T]
  Y_test[u] = (targets[t+T] > 0)

i = Input(shape=(T, D))
x = LSTM(50)(i)
x = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(i, x)
model.compile(
  loss='binary_crossentropy',
  optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001),
  metrics=['accuracy'],
)

r = model.fit(
  X_train, Y_train,
  batch_size=32,
  epochs=300,
  validation_data=(X_test, Y_test),
)
```

I tried this code below, but it doesn't make to much sense to me. How can I do it?

```
outputs = model.predict(X_test)
print(outputs.shape)
predictions = outputs[:,0]

plt.plot(Y_test, label='targets')
plt.plot(predictions, label='predictions')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: what does not make sense to you?

Comment: See the result: https://imgur.com/a/QFgLY3n . The targets should be go up or down (1 / 0), right? But I don't understand the result of the predictions. And how can I predict the stock price itself

Comment: you might be missing some lectures on neural networks... it predicts the probability to be 1, not a discrete value... you have to discretize them

Comment: For sure im missing some lectures, I am completely new to this area and this example is for learning purposes :). I know, that this prediction does not predict a certain value. But how can I achieve this? Thanks so far and in advance

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly**, stock market price prediction will come under the domain of [time series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series) analysis.

If you look at any open-high-low-close data, it always comes with a timestamp like this:

[OHLC stock data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sg7g.png)

Without a time column, it will be difficult to predict prices for the future.

**Secondly**, I'd like to know why you have used a [BCE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_functions_for_classification#Logistic_loss) loss function when it is not a classification problem? The correct metric to be used here is [MSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error).

**Thirdly**, since the data is time series varying, we don't apply any activation to the output layer, and it remains as one node. Hence, the [sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) you have used here needs to be removed.

> ```
> i = Input(shape=(T, D))
> x = LSTM(50)(i)
> x = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
> model = Model(i, x)
> model.compile(
>   loss='binary_crossentropy',
>   optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001),
>   metrics=['accuracy'],
> )
> ```

We can use any publicly available [OHLC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-high-low-close_chart) data set and see whether we can achieve our goal.

Using the [Yahoo Finance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_Finance) dataset with the same columns as your data, I am enclosing a **Colab Notebook** [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Z5Wf-Syma-vr86q-AIf-3AVDwgzFvNoj?usp=sharing#scrollTo=7KnEx3LGrXz1) here for your reference.

We have predicted the price of Google using the same methodology as you, with the help of [Keras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keras) [LSTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory), but with minor refinements.